# Is it possible to send request headers that are generated upon request in a http request

Tags: node.js, axios, xmlhttprequest, http-headers, http-post

I'm trying to log in to a website using Node.JS requests (I'm using Axios to do this) and I recieve error code 416 when I try to send a POST request to the API, it knows I'm a bot and blocks me from logging in.

However, I am able to send the request when I include these headers

```
        "exj5wzxnuf-a": "RbupF1JTWdsUNt03FvNScODb3Vl_ZSzaiJNyGwZu2bXiXp-IshPd5uoY8Z7WOzDwjw8qmiMjqdsG4Kn7h3WvZK04aYVKSLNOw5jVNlxHSdA5yMMRlSdhu_WfedQAuO2dxFL8CKMgR4MfZLaKQSwDuf2s_HLsN9qrkJMJPE3yAHCgJRcP6MuhgvHSpCoT1bW9wOmC1xAJFiW0O_iIO8RlJLElAfnopHBLVN4LxenPYRQ767FvzAygORJSQi-we43bz-wdLT8rxtngMmhawxDG4MN3a3flJyTBzhoChQJ4bg8f7IUELNEY-zjuhyImWmtGb080P1foY707Su87CWaHTxarOb8g22BVlKv35fOsycSLMHt6C4msCw-RFem7ZboZ5AsfM_OrOaf_LlgiwqLG7I-mZNt_19RGTxoVnJU5p_MSDpu-tchmm-Dl2uzzvX7mKA30bCRQqDvwHZtxLed1rqQaqNE5PII5ma23zPhYNfILA1HHoVkeenZGgG7Py0IQJotJqRDidncR6Rm6lRL0VETgthfxyiFHFIdN62LTp-XWjgyyl6xfBh16Wh88TB8oW2jBhIGg3Aa-dbpRXSGXxbWUUWwS-tF63X2laAzekoF57xheQUId7NCuacxH9ZpI76gb0_L5ZOZ9ZwslhkjvjqmppI5akllrb6bpK69N3kXiYyGbI5fvfPnEvgKIweqmtBmPr1psgLBGWkGZ_yjU15jUxjJowd581jJo0u_qscrwNOTQ2ctNDg0eUTzDKO5gYYrwby1M1XJeD9SHNVmKSw3qzfrZvOpcPfztGEcgc4z3zHAbNIPOGFVe7-i4z_jiHV9pJ9Vo6x33NuuLrwo8-P8GuFWP1ht6ETyR0HOuWK2wp7ERRcS5qXk_vEJQi9Cbh1eNerBfZgnU4_lNe3ZTbkv3Uibn0h-XhNC_zAtkU5OmXi6roENE0DBEAgOreR_P5PM-FtSvTj6axR6jdKcb0MmnBlrrdKpQxQHl2N_sjUOkBGGMniAmkq-nqzVs_oseI46teoEBAmjzza4YrkQniF6g-kfnyEMO980LciR7FWPYmqPRwk3B3VQ3Arp6FzRN84HcyJWX831s4xD1EyMgKwGW12P45HGJb2NgAs7Dgs4-o6241T2bargKgea3lHdsSHwc4_YMfgmNW9UzVksPpXWRrMUHEO37dR6DRCyK_DMJKAKRxq0nBOtgzL7MS-kCs9kDv4vhOCHiCg6CzGuZzR73ZE-z9B_Q05FllS3ah-eBsYO6XZJKD-q2DiSIsWmPR5su-8JNG2tcvOa5xMLfT2b9f2S52GI4k05McaAmCSe7xYMSRWWysDc3v0aXBY_lvHpQv4dODHOpsL1BkQG5DSYtuc_mkA8ThbeaS2YCbPAnd-aaW9hfER7r8yarsHe4zKJPxENEAvzgpZdaxIYt480rYxc_vkUg6QJg_rNJbOGi1jin7EYeSsDVuju1FPTQlvPrjU8IIStbPum0GtS8BRnhPGp7C5m6yBX3uQKX2XvrP1X5NY81fLmtTk_b_KNgLfAHqPE08SvDdiG6CvxHVbmz9IEKLHSW_ljwAjXzMGjerZIV19BqSSA1A1667cMW0M5WZNIg5trQmKeb4ciyjYmsuJSFxkljtlH4hDPJ5IbVn88Jg4wYOjF7CW8HU9mrHysIbvqapGj2EQg7dm68Y-yugi0hIqhllFaShZ-ySvewEhXOXo4gYDwZKfirrmxIYdL9QWJHiHM9Gyi7PsyIdv1CBYA6x-EtRQqeBoYe0-4yfA9zUKtFpaCPLDdC1tS713ymqhM8K8mleh6zINuUCpQMMSY6cyCvgaMVC2qESnUKh1OyFlrVymucxGx6jt3aCyNheHIus4WORs-6qxIoOWApAFqdIZE1s9tjRlnVqHhLe89D7ZrL9RzE_KbPSCAL7cUL5ZWGC3WCnwjKC9STulKpQKzXJUq4atBF1eUHh9MFmUPvF5iaevIEmLm0rRJ0HK9LOj-K3-h0-SyFFidFV71cUQvuoR9lmeqgmrjlCHy4DO5-BpCxkABJu_Z2HeZcmLUWJMQWObO7I9XXsGqlIdmrcV1XupMJYSVi4a7mJy6b4JJAAqho6hMIR6bla6ICS1Mv14O1ww4prbsVX-nfRCiH20d1QIWdw8knlb_Rv3BsbhmudQM8kt0gj5qVDkHg_2mly4g42dKo65HJajSpO8LfOo49H3rUc3Yb_FGwf7bMaFFdvBoX33KBMMzng6sh6uhRuFfNao9HAu9sjJVM7idm4wCb7LSSDlDYxodlhh4Ebl1-6gTc3IxbUOzTP5BNMWPWMjN2GajHXND0D9UVawV3511FW56G4k01TcEUFFbI-rT7c1fLgZUgi0dpj0hnNDUlhMMMxeWE7bnhITbDd6pwK5kjdbqgmkpt4WE4PGC0sOOq8QVRVEN4SnQpkzBJwcoohKlsUO63gZ5BL0pb6BjLm8zKRzMqrIwiG6F4xGv13VDus5-zCfe6m1LUbHmCcWTep4Z0o0yu_io2g4ANczihgaWQ6h4bg5C_mYxXKVkutDRh6hMeTK9_baVlGHYHaZMZw_Ok0MtYJ-um21bO_COCuAg_vOBcjaw8zdIis5_Jb1mWIJ9eytU4pYR2DGjTHIGTcAT_tzIbU7TT04XeU9PGVr4cCht6VI8O51adBcITp-ysj7wGFc1wXvz0Quv4Y7Zy3s2h-dhdt8elGBxn56PKE2wx-SrKWZ5WBr47ZHOQfqQ_JBit-bIexxEWIuGohXRx_a-BvsFwD5v5mna0xfbpfB7zO4EFI5lRZ2Gb0aPKTWk0cQHGpaB4ingDGSfJZ5uTmmODEcYGtcd5MZii9ASYg7i3MrrqYU6NkgM_jeRC98daTugim29NU9MZfPf9HISmqj9Ov8awslRMItch1rkmsmKpWSjxRP0yLbgi8AUpVFWZuuz8UQoe82OqRBfug9bVYyi5Ek8k0IfsyeCs_9q6_65gJ9uc8YA8VtyLb-OGTTZVsls_5E2DobAiCd75I9iQKWgneinZeXXZ0yPNemubOFTK30vb3HOcIwqojJuGnPp5ZmXRmrCzd6Z_3XiX2PKouMsPuv6ZEKAyLoAUdNcvmucI_m1U9lyIWPF0qibdL6QMoflsTOqOR04OIPTfOkklalegG9ba6NN3Ha9_IS84pOn3feRggQqLICt6BBk2xG3hqZxmtoPdos9EGKTK7aKyzalOfeqdK1-NdCug8wt2NmSxOsj01E8TpOjxNQ4-QjtD0aq0vp1nEEo3ifJvGpCURUSp15BmC2HTCUfT2fi7pQdXBJG_fjjplCqW0kQIoJCGMM6QuuQaMkBZskR1YJk1p8y_WT4jhw9eTCtyZGXioSjNS5je8Fzf0pKYZWNmYazPxfRcVs444i30Cy5PwWgA7_4X4zVwUPlmc3Y-tpuuM-KGBguYUKualz-AWrJVXgHHcHcyaT2jd1muhhLqARpX82_05vpE4ayAi-oudGrIaGkPlgWPkjpj2DgpsDNRaZgM3_Os19zogQqRis9zI5gVdErMyHhLRm0vEDP87wILXTXfkOJsH1Sttl7T1jVsHuIYNBmuPtgTGa9dQFEMpo73AzI9WHp6Y_esM2gac-tXMBjT4u_cC04pkjKd2yUQyVgYpdVE3o2whDayd1wIDV4-VUWVi9CG7rErLEW7hyOQuzzYMijQqiyZrwEG04cG1vgit8Au67bwB4zt9KTYMNMJoU5KKcqiBC3XUUvoudh2-BMmnpFByNfxTZz804rUT2KzQo976lvNIuMrGRVEZb3OcsEqVbz2_EUGF5bu5WXBRug5MJdqQ7qHM41RRwx9z-ovPnc32ojeBMbhSbd0MUD4meAgPJua-Emnvsuhs-eT-WZ3pIOSK-wENVthosZe1MzmHwPtT93ZSPUX8ztEWV_RcQlfVSw-pK9YlIriuAm-L4GazXB2rMpUxUoQ1fCyQ4bZQMGmQ29sprjPWk3lZ0PE-H_4_FFZdZnPHx8fU0nrDm02D5MPqRDT08sFBsyoFyIrG2_sZKL2ZoWa09_JbvvYp9YdLPeJ_73uZrwtR19CpHWXXf-uG0CtixbagAxSznd3XVjKBqulUPgjOcN72EMXkUvt9utYa4Dg5SBS7Tl66gGHa8VyULt0meFZbshyrWQnsDL1-oy8w3bHWeoupiLQ76Glz8oAnUO1jq9u44jzNwQsBmzK_DUNpSHxrLcb2HVU2uthNlVDBMMqhQ2hE-BuR6lH9CtrIgqlIaI4tv5gPxX_eaeO_6lH_xviXPgykoLc5evWQj_JVacpFHXFAoq8glh2MwyXwoWjEsjaGySA2--Glsl8B8wc-QuE4WnbQhh9fC4ho3FmSndbkeyuX-YWAczYrUWsJhLQZUHfpQQw3VSIijRmBBNe25KvmVUiwOZ5CQ_GlolI8YslpCP8GaSHVyOQCqLqoIQMNFUvxyWV_pFTWX1sTHSyi90punSep3CXIIUZPUy0-vKoCH-Q9CYvmMvppfv8F1HeGz9Vf-bSAbmq-Z6WDfJp2R7z8kPWAPIQMlVC5_Csgre6G08EsmggiafTxJiPyJ_oUVPgmHjxLkB7mmE-gWDFlbbrNn8S9mtnElyvtiwvQWvi6Xkln6elwUACnJt0_ZT4BUcb83kUEQ9yZR9Nytus-HYVD2tIb_Cz2yIbIqsfUFPd3y2oUUqvIB0me9zwQ5Cy3wOOKfZa2LJENIBHlczgJ9O2Pxz9Gf1I-pJIrC0rmFeVFTPozr3JIm7Q8T4dYny9Ddqk5aZbYtinHrG3ACH3FKHlfaPigd2kZav6o1C16e22-bFD_2_YjN89tDIRwf7jtWaHlmvUr8NPHk43h2tj4RVfJetfR-C7K2Ex91SgGBvwTfydKCakt0d-rRA3jwnPIYzTEjety_TcE4XAY-po48aTygY28WfJVKrURDOhaCCz0eXZn7iJcod_sj9Ar0ObmDeJnJsd3Ha2FGsqlCSBiC1noaNun3IVLh5yOotd_t0oq6C4D6eEBGIkJE_X0jmnHNLxFMbmh5VsCNR5WsKj0ymH3g9md_9uoRFaM_6HCuq8faN7sFOOnJHKeKSeCvkQ1LIU3aVYZA_HS_obFBk_3A3EXfM7DKQQniAmbVf49REBbLkyNGPb-v3PqZ8cDLQvftrErIQgVxJlVGbA_1z2AmcXN71dmr7RlbgPwTQuBMtMibdBPyRHcSs1y8WICd4a_bxxj9blXlDYhXhVwnPnb8O_BxN7CrdLvOyvKCD49ohKBtewKvOHnNvEr4_46ZEBYmdfcSGNdKNp8ALzbI43rZxaOebnNN3TbzWhFwMRvx4yxiWUNaUkXDdytqfbXAHsPdAMCyHbjxMKCuwT5G_gV8_abPJqMdcr2UhhjrB92aXxm0qdKcbZdfbnsn8OqnfYK1llNzWYvwNXeuCuihUN-_sUo2nvkekig2GDnO8FhG3iU8I0yZfBQyTmcMPZN4FlCJd2oA-lGdYzu-fJnZMjPHwMt_dS9hSjnmlfS-3_LB4iPAqhsg6HV9GrU9p_4t1KWs6dpdvks3ahDK14jI-9zWtwgzQ5LfiQ9GQ3C6FEGFUX7Ir08UGOauCJj5toFOy5a2ZCtZZDM-qT5keEzggZNWxF4Z4bL5-Zy8qno-eK7_GEA8fDaXOs-K5dHXjsjdfOz1OrcdfhzMI5SH26b6NmgnU896V8-EtsMB5I_75ue2utXiJM5mrF7RvIlaFb8CSwNVrV_scgta11ld7Z91bfLNOT4Dm4klrxapHm-XPYAfzaIxHdrPXf_zHeyxonLlJkxu2GEMmfIUQxVxguaY2r9RJWJSLuEDjxzHW78Un49i4NInGCOyyQLsBzxSd3goiKPql9RTlUkRDdxn1Ryh_uv1DvVPQcwoKt19JZ3K_BI5s8YC9YeODA1M62TUdi3NcVd7TBZ85sUKk-CS-im2-hIWqyBdRi-gD2lYM4m5VhkIL2_Ohl43YG4s0Dkwam4aYWsQ7NR-hnHXTvqeQbwJEkwMrBJBb-hkiahHTS5VOfR8WzwGcI--qp_R-XUo98-Ur_6JqiNSReaY-6lNr53hMxT06kr_Kgf2mDdLJQ0VOaFKhp1ijForq6xqg_H2ebk3lPoOUVYtJn1b-IKmtK-ZBCSmt-6fpJR7oXtaNVa1qGQPGC1ogXSCBJ650tOcZyuqxcvLZFBg37Xn_e7S_JIsTCckywI2Fs9Ak9Jkd1BqvD2OuSNe8nIO4chuz2-RftENxMeLDLLK70sBYlX4OtUp1y-ILJVTJUG9scfJFByqRPy-jdB2Gr5Hubhgrc65iYyfR5EHuXTPnoHzZduPJBclwTvE4cxxE5Kqmool5wjf_zBFI3Cev4",
        "exj5wzxnuf-b": "-hhwftc",
        "exj5wzxnuf-c": "AICj79B0AQAAWwRaKEQdWHuxBVwHSLBkxxkPerOXzasSuiqSKg-Kv7HnWVca",
        "exj5wzxnuf-d": "AAaihIjBDKGNgVGASZAQhISy1WIPir-x51lXGgAAAAB7Gu1BAIJ87WUFq_YBxIBaDNFjRjQ",
        "exj5wzxnuf-f": "A9OF-dB0AQAA92ZJMpyMR1wdPsOqMVFXJOhOz7CFTSckr6fvTlxsC6STL7XVAVAHP6-ucrtWwH8AAEB3AAAAAA==",
        "exj5wzxnuf-z": "q",
        "x-dtpc": "5$433847657_315h37vABKRGHMAMGCFOEADRPWCOMRCUCRNPNMK-0e30",
        "cookie": "mage-translation-file-version=%7B%7D; mage-translation-storage=%7B%7D; rxVisitor=1597657065467ULBBB9OKTTK11DMJHLGQAHTC70GL9DT7; _gcl_au=1.1.1712652071.1597657068; _fbp=fb.1.1597657070278.1086752850; __zlcmid=zjjMlQ9MPWHQkX; 4tagIi0FLf=AP1wXgZ0AQAAazAOkRBOE7hEmjNUJzygwFBQmsv9G9r9atg4koEnOduuzUXn|1|1|33745b0093f9669915ad744980d4dd0c4f77e98a; end_country=GB; _ALGOLIA=anonymous-347911f1-236e-4554-9eff-9725843d3453; __vero_visit=true; reese84=3:L6gP9QDAiqDxs8T9l0THvQ==:0QeNJqtsdNOlvDGAppOROyrcBTh7gyxuIMB9mP4xxYa0l5gvSkFjI69hBKxT/6hqMIFFT794ZoA7FGihZGUPt4u0oiZ/nrShRd4aFrd2VJPQ6uejs8+wQxpbPd5aYprXe0OxJDVDvQ96tkieO6bgjKbgZk7brwY8ZxHF8ZgtrVRHk2NBc3OWKpHtKafHjusGA7og/CVihKao418SpD5uSKE04XZ7EgUrs/U5QM3n0Stt/0AQRrMUMx/z7TEfd3x3zF4dswBN5bpj7JU2WxS+ahOFrwsjiZTWv0/p7t38jl5kwg3nRXWYaIO8k3TOXm0R4txAvNHwrF1mlCncfN10wCSFCyIj8FDsbSs5berYp8wqOHZRlttYmdqrhbDEFcGNX6syLf7dWeaVUnJuSs+HU9M3xtT+6aKHPAy3SN+e+uI=:5FK10KxOm8aJvLFsDkbGiAyDN1/J9THMop+1V2c38AU=; _gid=GA1.2.2080495832.1600924772; mage-messages=%5B%5D; mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; recently_viewed_product_previous=%7B%7D; recently_compared_product=%7B%7D; recently_compared_product_previous=%7B%7D; product_data_storage=%7B%7D; AKA_A2=A; veroEndId=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e; _aw_m_17184=17184_1601098103_2ded449124063933dfdef4995dab2658; _aw_m_17185=17185_1597658957_d8294fda2cde00c7341d8965ef3d5012; _uetsid=31997748eceae2e7518e7e895e5e3ab7; _uetvid=6cb2354bb46fc9e1b29b76e112355950; dtLatC=1; private_content_version=03b7ef01180c09942d139a623e0d834e; PHPSESSID=a6d8b35ef5802fa201a0216719f4db69; guest_token_GB=UbZpjPX7YXPiAXjohkjGreB1iik3mOIG; _ga=GA1.1.214888085.1597657068; _ga_BZDVJYZJVX=GS1.1.1601233158.33.1.1601233859.0; __vero_user=email_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e; form_key=yexFnSBVKKFUbKAF; mage-cache-sessid=true; section_data_ids=%7B%22customer%22%3A1601233862%2C%22compare-products%22%3A1601233862%2C%22magepal-gtm-jsdatalayer%22%3A1601233862%2C%22react-eventnotification%22%3A1601233862%2C%22last-ordered-items%22%3A1601233862%2C%22exponea-customer-data%22%3A1601233862%2C%22cart%22%3A1601233862%2C%22directory-data%22%3A1601233862%2C%22wishlist%22%3A1601233862%2C%22instant-purchase%22%3A1601233862%2C%22multiplewishlist%22%3A1601233862%2C%22persistent%22%3A1601233862%2C%22recently_viewed_product%22%3A1601233862%2C%22recently_compared_product%22%3A1601233862%2C%22product_data_storage%22%3A1601233862%2C%22paypal-billing-agreement%22%3A1601233862%2C%22checkout-fields%22%3A1601233862%2C%22collection-point-result%22%3A1601233862%2C%22messages%22%3A1601233862%7D; dtSa=true%7CU%7C-1%7CPage%3A%20%7C-%7C1601233860918%7C433859096_941%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.endclothing.com%2Fgb%2Fcustomer%2Faccount%2FlogoutSuccess%2F%7C%7C1601233860943%7C%7C; __veroc4=%5B%7B%22command%22%3A%5B%22events_track%22%2C%22log_out%22%2C%7B%22userAgent%22%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F85.0.4183.121%20Safari%2F537.36%22%2C%22platform%22%3A%22Win32%22%2C%22language%22%3A%22en-GB%22%7D%2C%7B%22time%22%3A1601233859848%2C%22order%22%3A1%7D%5D%2C%22job_id%22%3A%221601233859847_8545%22%7D%2C%7B%22command%22%3A%5B%22users_track%22%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22email_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e%22%2C%22userAgent%22%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F85.0.4183.121%20Safari%2F537.36%22%2C%22platform%22%3A%22Win32%22%2C%22language%22%3A%22en-GB%22%7D%5D%2C%22job_id%22%3A%221601233859854_9918%22%7D%5D; dtCookie=v_4_srv_5_sn_DB0A3193A3CB1BEBBBFBAD07FFB206BA_app-3A6abe796a369c80f6_1_app-3A063974da2eae43d3_1_ol_0_perc_100000_mul_1; dtPC=5$433847657_315h37vABKRGHMAMGCFOEADRPWCOMRCUCRNPNMK-0e30; rxvt=1601235689673|1601233014205"
```

The only issue with this is that these headers are only generated within the response when I send the login request, is there any way that I'd be able to dynamically generate these headers myself just before I execute the POST request with Axios?

Here's the working Axios request which returns a status code of 200:

```
const usrPass = {
        username: "mygmail@gmail.com",
        password: "password"
      };
    axios.post('https://www.endclothing.com/gb/customer/ajax/login', usrPass, {headers: {
        "accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "accept-language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "exj5wzxnuf-a": "RbupF1JTWdsUNt03FvNScODb3Vl_ZSzaiJNyGwZu2bXiXp-IshPd5uoY8Z7WOzDwjw8qmiMjqdsG4Kn7h3WvZK04aYVKSLNOw5jVNlxHSdA5yMMRlSdhu_WfedQAuO2dxFL8CKMgR4MfZLaKQSwDuf2s_HLsN9qrkJMJPE3yAHCgJRcP6MuhgvHSpCoT1bW9wOmC1xAJFiW0O_iIO8RlJLElAfnopHBLVN4LxenPYRQ767FvzAygORJSQi-we43bz-wdLT8rxtngMmhawxDG4MN3a3flJyTBzhoChQJ4bg8f7IUELNEY-zjuhyImWmtGb080P1foY707Su87CWaHTxarOb8g22BVlKv35fOsycSLMHt6C4msCw-RFem7ZboZ5AsfM_OrOaf_LlgiwqLG7I-mZNt_19RGTxoVnJU5p_MSDpu-tchmm-Dl2uzzvX7mKA30bCRQqDvwHZtxLed1rqQaqNE5PII5ma23zPhYNfILA1HHoVkeenZGgG7Py0IQJotJqRDidncR6Rm6lRL0VETgthfxyiFHFIdN62LTp-XWjgyyl6xfBh16Wh88TB8oW2jBhIGg3Aa-dbpRXSGXxbWUUWwS-tF63X2laAzekoF57xheQUId7NCuacxH9ZpI76gb0_L5ZOZ9ZwslhkjvjqmppI5akllrb6bpK69N3kXiYyGbI5fvfPnEvgKIweqmtBmPr1psgLBGWkGZ_yjU15jUxjJowd581jJo0u_qscrwNOTQ2ctNDg0eUTzDKO5gYYrwby1M1XJeD9SHNVmKSw3qzfrZvOpcPfztGEcgc4z3zHAbNIPOGFVe7-i4z_jiHV9pJ9Vo6x33NuuLrwo8-P8GuFWP1ht6ETyR0HOuWK2wp7ERRcS5qXk_vEJQi9Cbh1eNerBfZgnU4_lNe3ZTbkv3Uibn0h-XhNC_zAtkU5OmXi6roENE0DBEAgOreR_P5PM-FtSvTj6axR6jdKcb0MmnBlrrdKpQxQHl2N_sjUOkBGGMniAmkq-nqzVs_oseI46teoEBAmjzza4YrkQniF6g-kfnyEMO980LciR7FWPYmqPRwk3B3VQ3Arp6FzRN84HcyJWX831s4xD1EyMgKwGW12P45HGJb2NgAs7Dgs4-o6241T2bargKgea3lHdsSHwc4_YMfgmNW9UzVksPpXWRrMUHEO37dR6DRCyK_DMJKAKRxq0nBOtgzL7MS-kCs9kDv4vhOCHiCg6CzGuZzR73ZE-z9B_Q05FllS3ah-eBsYO6XZJKD-q2DiSIsWmPR5su-8JNG2tcvOa5xMLfT2b9f2S52GI4k05McaAmCSe7xYMSRWWysDc3v0aXBY_lvHpQv4dODHOpsL1BkQG5DSYtuc_mkA8ThbeaS2YCbPAnd-aaW9hfER7r8yarsHe4zKJPxENEAvzgpZdaxIYt480rYxc_vkUg6QJg_rNJbOGi1jin7EYeSsDVuju1FPTQlvPrjU8IIStbPum0GtS8BRnhPGp7C5m6yBX3uQKX2XvrP1X5NY81fLmtTk_b_KNgLfAHqPE08SvDdiG6CvxHVbmz9IEKLHSW_ljwAjXzMGjerZIV19BqSSA1A1667cMW0M5WZNIg5trQmKeb4ciyjYmsuJSFxkljtlH4hDPJ5IbVn88Jg4wYOjF7CW8HU9mrHysIbvqapGj2EQg7dm68Y-yugi0hIqhllFaShZ-ySvewEhXOXo4gYDwZKfirrmxIYdL9QWJHiHM9Gyi7PsyIdv1CBYA6x-EtRQqeBoYe0-4yfA9zUKtFpaCPLDdC1tS713ymqhM8K8mleh6zINuUCpQMMSY6cyCvgaMVC2qESnUKh1OyFlrVymucxGx6jt3aCyNheHIus4WORs-6qxIoOWApAFqdIZE1s9tjRlnVqHhLe89D7ZrL9RzE_KbPSCAL7cUL5ZWGC3WCnwjKC9STulKpQKzXJUq4atBF1eUHh9MFmUPvF5iaevIEmLm0rRJ0HK9LOj-K3-h0-SyFFidFV71cUQvuoR9lmeqgmrjlCHy4DO5-BpCxkABJu_Z2HeZcmLUWJMQWObO7I9XXsGqlIdmrcV1XupMJYSVi4a7mJy6b4JJAAqho6hMIR6bla6ICS1Mv14O1ww4prbsVX-nfRCiH20d1QIWdw8knlb_Rv3BsbhmudQM8kt0gj5qVDkHg_2mly4g42dKo65HJajSpO8LfOo49H3rUc3Yb_FGwf7bMaFFdvBoX33KBMMzng6sh6uhRuFfNao9HAu9sjJVM7idm4wCb7LSSDlDYxodlhh4Ebl1-6gTc3IxbUOzTP5BNMWPWMjN2GajHXND0D9UVawV3511FW56G4k01TcEUFFbI-rT7c1fLgZUgi0dpj0hnNDUlhMMMxeWE7bnhITbDd6pwK5kjdbqgmkpt4WE4PGC0sOOq8QVRVEN4SnQpkzBJwcoohKlsUO63gZ5BL0pb6BjLm8zKRzMqrIwiG6F4xGv13VDus5-zCfe6m1LUbHmCcWTep4Z0o0yu_io2g4ANczihgaWQ6h4bg5C_mYxXKVkutDRh6hMeTK9_baVlGHYHaZMZw_Ok0MtYJ-um21bO_COCuAg_vOBcjaw8zdIis5_Jb1mWIJ9eytU4pYR2DGjTHIGTcAT_tzIbU7TT04XeU9PGVr4cCht6VI8O51adBcITp-ysj7wGFc1wXvz0Quv4Y7Zy3s2h-dhdt8elGBxn56PKE2wx-SrKWZ5WBr47ZHOQfqQ_JBit-bIexxEWIuGohXRx_a-BvsFwD5v5mna0xfbpfB7zO4EFI5lRZ2Gb0aPKTWk0cQHGpaB4ingDGSfJZ5uTmmODEcYGtcd5MZii9ASYg7i3MrrqYU6NkgM_jeRC98daTugim29NU9MZfPf9HISmqj9Ov8awslRMItch1rkmsmKpWSjxRP0yLbgi8AUpVFWZuuz8UQoe82OqRBfug9bVYyi5Ek8k0IfsyeCs_9q6_65gJ9uc8YA8VtyLb-OGTTZVsls_5E2DobAiCd75I9iQKWgneinZeXXZ0yPNemubOFTK30vb3HOcIwqojJuGnPp5ZmXRmrCzd6Z_3XiX2PKouMsPuv6ZEKAyLoAUdNcvmucI_m1U9lyIWPF0qibdL6QMoflsTOqOR04OIPTfOkklalegG9ba6NN3Ha9_IS84pOn3feRggQqLICt6BBk2xG3hqZxmtoPdos9EGKTK7aKyzalOfeqdK1-NdCug8wt2NmSxOsj01E8TpOjxNQ4-QjtD0aq0vp1nEEo3ifJvGpCURUSp15BmC2HTCUfT2fi7pQdXBJG_fjjplCqW0kQIoJCGMM6QuuQaMkBZskR1YJk1p8y_WT4jhw9eTCtyZGXioSjNS5je8Fzf0pKYZWNmYazPxfRcVs444i30Cy5PwWgA7_4X4zVwUPlmc3Y-tpuuM-KGBguYUKualz-AWrJVXgHHcHcyaT2jd1muhhLqARpX82_05vpE4ayAi-oudGrIaGkPlgWPkjpj2DgpsDNRaZgM3_Os19zogQqRis9zI5gVdErMyHhLRm0vEDP87wILXTXfkOJsH1Sttl7T1jVsHuIYNBmuPtgTGa9dQFEMpo73AzI9WHp6Y_esM2gac-tXMBjT4u_cC04pkjKd2yUQyVgYpdVE3o2whDayd1wIDV4-VUWVi9CG7rErLEW7hyOQuzzYMijQqiyZrwEG04cG1vgit8Au67bwB4zt9KTYMNMJoU5KKcqiBC3XUUvoudh2-BMmnpFByNfxTZz804rUT2KzQo976lvNIuMrGRVEZb3OcsEqVbz2_EUGF5bu5WXBRug5MJdqQ7qHM41RRwx9z-ovPnc32ojeBMbhSbd0MUD4meAgPJua-Emnvsuhs-eT-WZ3pIOSK-wENVthosZe1MzmHwPtT93ZSPUX8ztEWV_RcQlfVSw-pK9YlIriuAm-L4GazXB2rMpUxUoQ1fCyQ4bZQMGmQ29sprjPWk3lZ0PE-H_4_FFZdZnPHx8fU0nrDm02D5MPqRDT08sFBsyoFyIrG2_sZKL2ZoWa09_JbvvYp9YdLPeJ_73uZrwtR19CpHWXXf-uG0CtixbagAxSznd3XVjKBqulUPgjOcN72EMXkUvt9utYa4Dg5SBS7Tl66gGHa8VyULt0meFZbshyrWQnsDL1-oy8w3bHWeoupiLQ76Glz8oAnUO1jq9u44jzNwQsBmzK_DUNpSHxrLcb2HVU2uthNlVDBMMqhQ2hE-BuR6lH9CtrIgqlIaI4tv5gPxX_eaeO_6lH_xviXPgykoLc5evWQj_JVacpFHXFAoq8glh2MwyXwoWjEsjaGySA2--Glsl8B8wc-QuE4WnbQhh9fC4ho3FmSndbkeyuX-YWAczYrUWsJhLQZUHfpQQw3VSIijRmBBNe25KvmVUiwOZ5CQ_GlolI8YslpCP8GaSHVyOQCqLqoIQMNFUvxyWV_pFTWX1sTHSyi90punSep3CXIIUZPUy0-vKoCH-Q9CYvmMvppfv8F1HeGz9Vf-bSAbmq-Z6WDfJp2R7z8kPWAPIQMlVC5_Csgre6G08EsmggiafTxJiPyJ_oUVPgmHjxLkB7mmE-gWDFlbbrNn8S9mtnElyvtiwvQWvi6Xkln6elwUACnJt0_ZT4BUcb83kUEQ9yZR9Nytus-HYVD2tIb_Cz2yIbIqsfUFPd3y2oUUqvIB0me9zwQ5Cy3wOOKfZa2LJENIBHlczgJ9O2Pxz9Gf1I-pJIrC0rmFeVFTPozr3JIm7Q8T4dYny9Ddqk5aZbYtinHrG3ACH3FKHlfaPigd2kZav6o1C16e22-bFD_2_YjN89tDIRwf7jtWaHlmvUr8NPHk43h2tj4RVfJetfR-C7K2Ex91SgGBvwTfydKCakt0d-rRA3jwnPIYzTEjety_TcE4XAY-po48aTygY28WfJVKrURDOhaCCz0eXZn7iJcod_sj9Ar0ObmDeJnJsd3Ha2FGsqlCSBiC1noaNun3IVLh5yOotd_t0oq6C4D6eEBGIkJE_X0jmnHNLxFMbmh5VsCNR5WsKj0ymH3g9md_9uoRFaM_6HCuq8faN7sFOOnJHKeKSeCvkQ1LIU3aVYZA_HS_obFBk_3A3EXfM7DKQQniAmbVf49REBbLkyNGPb-v3PqZ8cDLQvftrErIQgVxJlVGbA_1z2AmcXN71dmr7RlbgPwTQuBMtMibdBPyRHcSs1y8WICd4a_bxxj9blXlDYhXhVwnPnb8O_BxN7CrdLvOyvKCD49ohKBtewKvOHnNvEr4_46ZEBYmdfcSGNdKNp8ALzbI43rZxaOebnNN3TbzWhFwMRvx4yxiWUNaUkXDdytqfbXAHsPdAMCyHbjxMKCuwT5G_gV8_abPJqMdcr2UhhjrB92aXxm0qdKcbZdfbnsn8OqnfYK1llNzWYvwNXeuCuihUN-_sUo2nvkekig2GDnO8FhG3iU8I0yZfBQyTmcMPZN4FlCJd2oA-lGdYzu-fJnZMjPHwMt_dS9hSjnmlfS-3_LB4iPAqhsg6HV9GrU9p_4t1KWs6dpdvks3ahDK14jI-9zWtwgzQ5LfiQ9GQ3C6FEGFUX7Ir08UGOauCJj5toFOy5a2ZCtZZDM-qT5keEzggZNWxF4Z4bL5-Zy8qno-eK7_GEA8fDaXOs-K5dHXjsjdfOz1OrcdfhzMI5SH26b6NmgnU896V8-EtsMB5I_75ue2utXiJM5mrF7RvIlaFb8CSwNVrV_scgta11ld7Z91bfLNOT4Dm4klrxapHm-XPYAfzaIxHdrPXf_zHeyxonLlJkxu2GEMmfIUQxVxguaY2r9RJWJSLuEDjxzHW78Un49i4NInGCOyyQLsBzxSd3goiKPql9RTlUkRDdxn1Ryh_uv1DvVPQcwoKt19JZ3K_BI5s8YC9YeODA1M62TUdi3NcVd7TBZ85sUKk-CS-im2-hIWqyBdRi-gD2lYM4m5VhkIL2_Ohl43YG4s0Dkwam4aYWsQ7NR-hnHXTvqeQbwJEkwMrBJBb-hkiahHTS5VOfR8WzwGcI--qp_R-XUo98-Ur_6JqiNSReaY-6lNr53hMxT06kr_Kgf2mDdLJQ0VOaFKhp1ijForq6xqg_H2ebk3lPoOUVYtJn1b-IKmtK-ZBCSmt-6fpJR7oXtaNVa1qGQPGC1ogXSCBJ650tOcZyuqxcvLZFBg37Xn_e7S_JIsTCckywI2Fs9Ak9Jkd1BqvD2OuSNe8nIO4chuz2-RftENxMeLDLLK70sBYlX4OtUp1y-ILJVTJUG9scfJFByqRPy-jdB2Gr5Hubhgrc65iYyfR5EHuXTPnoHzZduPJBclwTvE4cxxE5Kqmool5wjf_zBFI3Cev4",
        "exj5wzxnuf-b": "-hhwftc",
        "exj5wzxnuf-c": "AICj79B0AQAAWwRaKEQdWHuxBVwHSLBkxxkPerOXzasSuiqSKg-Kv7HnWVca",
        "exj5wzxnuf-d": "AAaihIjBDKGNgVGASZAQhISy1WIPir-x51lXGgAAAAB7Gu1BAIJ87WUFq_YBxIBaDNFjRjQ",
        "exj5wzxnuf-f": "A9OF-dB0AQAA92ZJMpyMR1wdPsOqMVFXJOhOz7CFTSckr6fvTlxsC6STL7XVAVAHP6-ucrtWwH8AAEB3AAAAAA==",
        "exj5wzxnuf-z": "q",
        "sec-fetch-dest": "empty",
        "sec-fetch-mode": "cors",
        "sec-fetch-site": "same-origin",
        "x-dtpc": "5$433847657_315h37vABKRGHMAMGCFOEADRPWCOMRCUCRNPNMK-0e30",
        "x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest",
        "cookie": "mage-translation-file-version=%7B%7D; mage-translation-storage=%7B%7D; rxVisitor=1597657065467ULBBB9OKTTK11DMJHLGQAHTC70GL9DT7; _gcl_au=1.1.1712652071.1597657068; _fbp=fb.1.1597657070278.1086752850; __zlcmid=zjjMlQ9MPWHQkX; 4tagIi0FLf=AP1wXgZ0AQAAazAOkRBOE7hEmjNUJzygwFBQmsv9G9r9atg4koEnOduuzUXn|1|1|33745b0093f9669915ad744980d4dd0c4f77e98a; end_country=GB; _ALGOLIA=anonymous-347911f1-236e-4554-9eff-9725843d3453; __vero_visit=true; reese84=3:L6gP9QDAiqDxs8T9l0THvQ==:0QeNJqtsdNOlvDGAppOROyrcBTh7gyxuIMB9mP4xxYa0l5gvSkFjI69hBKxT/6hqMIFFT794ZoA7FGihZGUPt4u0oiZ/nrShRd4aFrd2VJPQ6uejs8+wQxpbPd5aYprXe0OxJDVDvQ96tkieO6bgjKbgZk7brwY8ZxHF8ZgtrVRHk2NBc3OWKpHtKafHjusGA7og/CVihKao418SpD5uSKE04XZ7EgUrs/U5QM3n0Stt/0AQRrMUMx/z7TEfd3x3zF4dswBN5bpj7JU2WxS+ahOFrwsjiZTWv0/p7t38jl5kwg3nRXWYaIO8k3TOXm0R4txAvNHwrF1mlCncfN10wCSFCyIj8FDsbSs5berYp8wqOHZRlttYmdqrhbDEFcGNX6syLf7dWeaVUnJuSs+HU9M3xtT+6aKHPAy3SN+e+uI=:5FK10KxOm8aJvLFsDkbGiAyDN1/J9THMop+1V2c38AU=; _gid=GA1.2.2080495832.1600924772; mage-messages=%5B%5D; mage-cache-storage=%7B%7D; mage-cache-storage-section-invalidation=%7B%7D; recently_viewed_product=%7B%7D; recently_viewed_product_previous=%7B%7D; recently_compared_product=%7B%7D; recently_compared_product_previous=%7B%7D; product_data_storage=%7B%7D; AKA_A2=A; veroEndId=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e; _aw_m_17184=17184_1601098103_2ded449124063933dfdef4995dab2658; _aw_m_17185=17185_1597658957_d8294fda2cde00c7341d8965ef3d5012; _uetsid=31997748eceae2e7518e7e895e5e3ab7; _uetvid=6cb2354bb46fc9e1b29b76e112355950; dtLatC=1; private_content_version=03b7ef01180c09942d139a623e0d834e; PHPSESSID=a6d8b35ef5802fa201a0216719f4db69; guest_token_GB=UbZpjPX7YXPiAXjohkjGreB1iik3mOIG; _ga=GA1.1.214888085.1597657068; _ga_BZDVJYZJVX=GS1.1.1601233158.33.1.1601233859.0; __vero_user=email_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e; form_key=yexFnSBVKKFUbKAF; mage-cache-sessid=true; section_data_ids=%7B%22customer%22%3A1601233862%2C%22compare-products%22%3A1601233862%2C%22magepal-gtm-jsdatalayer%22%3A1601233862%2C%22react-eventnotification%22%3A1601233862%2C%22last-ordered-items%22%3A1601233862%2C%22exponea-customer-data%22%3A1601233862%2C%22cart%22%3A1601233862%2C%22directory-data%22%3A1601233862%2C%22wishlist%22%3A1601233862%2C%22instant-purchase%22%3A1601233862%2C%22multiplewishlist%22%3A1601233862%2C%22persistent%22%3A1601233862%2C%22recently_viewed_product%22%3A1601233862%2C%22recently_compared_product%22%3A1601233862%2C%22product_data_storage%22%3A1601233862%2C%22paypal-billing-agreement%22%3A1601233862%2C%22checkout-fields%22%3A1601233862%2C%22collection-point-result%22%3A1601233862%2C%22messages%22%3A1601233862%7D; dtSa=true%7CU%7C-1%7CPage%3A%20%7C-%7C1601233860918%7C433859096_941%7Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.endclothing.com%2Fgb%2Fcustomer%2Faccount%2FlogoutSuccess%2F%7C%7C1601233860943%7C%7C; __veroc4=%5B%7B%22command%22%3A%5B%22events_track%22%2C%22log_out%22%2C%7B%22userAgent%22%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F85.0.4183.121%20Safari%2F537.36%22%2C%22platform%22%3A%22Win32%22%2C%22language%22%3A%22en-GB%22%7D%2C%7B%22time%22%3A1601233859848%2C%22order%22%3A1%7D%5D%2C%22job_id%22%3A%221601233859847_8545%22%7D%2C%7B%22command%22%3A%5B%22users_track%22%2C%7B%22id%22%3A%22email_d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e%22%2C%22userAgent%22%3A%22Mozilla%2F5.0%20(Windows%20NT%2010.0%3B%20Win64%3B%20x64)%20AppleWebKit%2F537.36%20(KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko)%20Chrome%2F85.0.4183.121%20Safari%2F537.36%22%2C%22platform%22%3A%22Win32%22%2C%22language%22%3A%22en-GB%22%7D%5D%2C%22job_id%22%3A%221601233859854_9918%22%7D%5D; dtCookie=v_4_srv_5_sn_DB0A3193A3CB1BEBBBFBAD07FFB206BA_app-3A6abe796a369c80f6_1_app-3A063974da2eae43d3_1_ol_0_perc_100000_mul_1; dtPC=5$433847657_315h37vABKRGHMAMGCFOEADRPWCOMRCUCRNPNMK-0e30; rxvt=1601235689673|1601233014205"
      
    }})
```

*The cookies will be old so if you wish to generate new headers in order to test then this is the home page uri
https://www.endclothing.com/gb/
In order to view the network request you have to log in via the button on the top right of the home page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You answered your own question, no?

> The cookies will be old so if you wish to generate new headers in order to test then this is the home page uri https://www.endclothing.com/gb/ In order to view the network request you have to log in via the button on the top right of the home page"

You could send a get request to https://www.endclothing.com/gb/ and it would respond with the headers

Comment: Yeah, the website use ShapeSecurity bot protection which runs a javascript file in the browser which generates the headers so if i wanted to get valid headers I'd have to deobfuscate and change the script so i could use it. Tahnks for the answer, i forgot this post was still up haha